# What is the proper way to combine synchronous code and promises?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await, es6-promise

I am writing a function that serves as an API intermediary function between an actual server API call, and userland.
This function validates some input data (sync), transforms it as appropriate(sync), reads some other data (async). The results are then merged and used to finally make the actual call to a server endpoint (async).
This function must always return a promise, and all execution flow in higher-level APIs using it should be handled through promise chaining.

However, I am having trouble figuring out if I'm doing it the proper way. And also, I have some related questions that I cannot find an answer to.

This is the code I wrote up until now:

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as MyAPI from "./MyAPI";
import querystring from "querystring";

function fetchFromServerEndpoint(route, routeParams, optQueryParams) {
    // Is it ok to use Promise.all() to combine sync and async code as below?
    return Promise.all([
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const routeReplacedParams = route.replace(/{([^{/]*?)}/g, (match, paramName) => {
                const paramValue = routeParams[paramName];

                if (paramValue === undefined) {
                    // Here I need to terminate execution of the replacer function
                    // and reject this promise
                    // Is it ok to `throw` here?
                    throw "UNDEFINED_ROUTE_PARAMETER";

                    // Can I somehow `return reject(...)` here instead of throw-ing?
                }

                return paramValue;
            });

            return resolve(routeReplacedParams);
        }),
        // Is it fine to use async to mock a promise with synchronous code?
        async function(){
            return querystring.stringify(optQueryParams);
        }),
        // This is part of a custom API, returns a legit promise
        MyAPI.getAuthorizationAsync(),
    ]).then(([finalRoute, queryParams, authToken]) => {
        // axios library, all APIs will return a promise
        return axios.get(`${finalRoute}?${queryParams}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Basic ${authToken}`
            }
        });
    });
}
```

My questions are:

1. What is a proper way to stop execution of a block of code when an error situation arises, from a syncrhonous function, inside a promise? Moreover, like in the replacer function of `String.replace`, is it ok to 'throw' there? Can you suggest any better option, or maybe, a more promise-friendly approach?
2. Marking a function with `async` will implictly create a promise, and will also implictly convert (uncaught) `throw`s into `Promise.reject()`s and returns intro `Promise.resolve()`s. The benefit is that you can write code identically to a normal synchronous function, but still have it behave like a promise, so you can chain promises to it. Is this understanding of mine incorrect? Are there drawbacks (or benefits, other than what I just described) that I should be aware of?
3. I used Promise.all() in order to combine the results of multiple, independent stages of the function execution. I suppose this is fine, but are there any other ways to deal with this situation? Or maybe it's a bad practice? Should I, instead, chain promises, and pass-through results from a promise to the next until, I reach the level where I need to use all of them?

Comment: If you throw inside an `async` function or inside a `.then()` handler, it will reject the host promise with whatever error you throw as the reject reason.  That is an expected use.  Keep in mind that throwing inside a plain callback (not a promise callback) is not usually advised because the exception doesn't go anywhere you can catch it or handle it.

Comment: Putting entirely synchronous code inside an `async` function would rarely make sense.  That just complicates its use and prevents you from returning a normal value.  Remember, you can `try/catch` exceptions in synchronous code just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a proper way to stop execution of a block of code when an error situation arises, from a syncrhonous function, inside a promise? Moreover, like in the replacer function of String.replace, is it ok to 'throw' there? Can you suggest any better option, or maybe, a more promise-friendly approach?

It is ok to throw there.  The Promise executor function does catch synchronous exceptions that occur in the executor function and turn them into a rejected promise.

Whether that's a good thing to do really depends upon what you want to happen.  If you want the promise in the calling function to reject, then you can just throw from the synchronous function and that will bubble up to the promise in the asynchronous caller and cause a reject.  Otherwise, you're also free to use regular synchronous techniques such as return an error condition from the synchronous function, check for that error in the caller and then act accordingly.  So, like any other design, it totally depends upon how you want your synchronous function to be called and how the caller should check for errors or handle errors.  Sometimes an error code returned is right and sometimes throwing an exception is right.

As an example, in this if calling `randomSyncFunctionThatMightThrow()` throws, then the callers promise will get rejected automatically and the `.catch()` handler will be hit.

```
function randomSyncFunctionThatMightThrow() {
    // other logic
    throw new Error("random error");
}

someFuncThatReturnsPromise().then(arg => {
    // bunch of logic here
    randomSyncFunctionThatMightThrow();
    // other logic here
    return someThing;
}).then(result => {
    console.log(finalResult);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

> Marking a function with async will implictly create a promise, and will also implictly convert (uncaught) throws into Promise.reject()s and returns intro Promise.resolve()s. The benefit is that you can write code identically to a normal synchronous function, but still have it behave like a promise, so you can chain promises to it. Is this understanding of mine incorrect?

Sounds right to me.  `async` functions have a `try/catch` build in and automatically catch any exceptions and turn them into a rejected promise.

> Are there drawbacks (or benefits, other than what I just described) that I should be aware of?

Forcing all synchronous code to handle normal ordinary return results asynchronously with promises has its limits.  You wouldn't use it for every synchronous function in your whole program for obvious coding complexity reasons.  Asynchronous code is more time consuming to write and test so I don't go looking for ways to make ordinary synchronous things start returning promises and make all callers deal with the asynchronously.  There might be an occasional time when some synchronous code is easier to mix with asynchronous code if it also deals in promises.  But, that's not the ordinary use of synchronous code.

> I used Promise.all() in order to combine the results of multiple, independent stages of the function execution. I suppose this is fine, but are there any other ways to deal with this situation? Or maybe it's a bad practice? Should I, instead, chain promises, and pass-through results from a promise to the next until, I reach the level where I need to use all of them?

`Promise.all()` is for situations where you want to have multiple independent and parallel, asynchronous executions chains all in-flight at the same time and you just want to know when they are all done and have all the results at once.  Promise chaining is for when you want to sequence things in order one after the other for any number of reasons, but often because step #2 depends upon the result of step #1.  You should pick `Promise.all()` vs. chaining depending upon the needs of the asynchronous code (executing in parallel vs. executing in sequence).

Putting synchronous code into a `Promise.all()` can work just fine (you don't even have to wrap it in a promise as `Promise.all()` will accept a return value from running a function too), but usually, there's no point.  The synchronous code is blocking and synchronous so you usually don't get any parallelism by putting the synchronous code in the `Promise.all()`.  I would typically just run the synchronous code either before or after the `Promise.all()` and not mix it in with the actual asynchronous promises.

> However, I am having trouble figuring out if I'm doing it the proper way.

I've included below an alternate implementation.  I don't, as a general practice, like wrapping synchronous code in promises, so this is my alternative.  I've used an `async` function both so I can use `await` and so that synchronous exceptions are automatically converted into rejected promise and your function's contract was already returning a promise so this is just a simpler way of achieving the same result (in my opinion).  Of course, this is all just coding style which is largely governed by opinions.

Here's how I would likely write your code:

```
async function fetchFromServerEndpoint(route, routeParams, optQueryParams) {
    const finalRoute = route.replace(/{([^{/]*?)}/g, (match, paramName) => {
        const paramValue = routeParams[paramName];

        if (paramValue === undefined) {
            // Here I need to abort execution of the replacer function
            // parent promise will be rejected
            throw new Error("UNDEFINED_ROUTE_PARAMETER");
        }
        return paramValue;
    });
    const queryParms = querystring.stringify(optQueryParams);
    const authToken = await MyAPI.getAuthorizationAsync();
    return axios.get(`${finalRoute}?${queryParams}`, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${authToken}`
        }
    });
}
```

If you really don't like `await`, you can avoid that here by changing the end to:

```
    return MyAPI.getAuthorizationAsync().then(authToken => {
        return axios.get(`${finalRoute}?${queryParams}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Basic ${authToken}`
            }
        });
    });
```

But, as I've said in a comment elsewhere, I think `await` is a useful tool (when used appropriately) that lets you write simpler code.

Comment: Lovely answer, really put to rest some of my doubts! Just to be clear, I would never force every synchronous function to handle things asynchronously, that is wrong by definition :) And I don't hate await that much, I can tolerate appropriate usage :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `await` in `try catch` block. That's readable, and doesn't lead to callback hell.

```
async function f() {

  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://no-such-url');
  } catch(err) {
    alert(err); // TypeError: failed to fetch
  }
}

f();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: I actually don't like using await because it takes away the feeling of the asynchronicity of the code execution. Also, using nested awaits (such as, awaiting async functions inside other awaited async functions) leads most of the times to completely blocking the main JS thread. If you're dealing with UIs, this can cause stuttering, and bad user experience. Use await carefully, usually, chaining promises is a better deal.

Comment: @cristian - It is NOT true that you can always right better code by chaining promises and avoiding `await`.  There is branching asynchronous logic that is multiple times simpler and easier to write and debug when using `await` vs. being forced into deeply nested `.then()` chains.  It's just a new tool in the toolbox for you to learn and come to appreciate how you can write better code with it.

Comment: just gonna drop this here
https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9

Comment: @MarekKamiński If you're deep nesting chains of promises, you didn't understand how they're supposed to work. The article you posted is awful, and in my opinion, purposedly leaves out and does not evaluate the use cases and implications of using a promises or async/await approach. Using each appropriately is a better choice that simply using only one. I will not continue arguing on this since it's out of the scope of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. proper way to terminate asynchronous block is by returning a rejected promise or throwing an error, which will reject the promise with 'uncaught error' exception which hopefully contains the stack trace
2. yes `async` synchronously returns a promise, similar to how `get` and `set` deal with synchronous access. there's a pattern of using thunks where (as opposed to synchronous access) you invoke a 'noun' function to actually derive eg. `foobar()` as opposed to just accessing `foobar`. anyways, you can chain promises but enter nested tabbed blocks, so people use `await` to keep the composing function flat
3. `Promise.all` is the correct way to halt until all dependent promises resolve, and I've seen documentation for Puppeteer init an event and add a listener at the same time, but I'm not sure if threads have guaranteed order.

There are two mainstream, asynchronous JS (redux) libraries called `redux-thunk` and `sagas`.

Redux thunk promotes declarative promise chain-looking actions

Sagas uses while-loop polling of function generators' returned iterator's yielded 'effects' and allows for less semantic, but more dynamic scheduling. I didn't like that we couldn't kick off sagas directly; they only work by listening for other actions to 'tag along' with like `dispatch('MY_EVENT_START')` which is immediately consumed and loosely coupled to the actual functionality that runs (registered in both dispatcher/listener). Normally, if a `Promise.all` block fails, the rest of them would keep running (and their dependent chains), but sagas would stop invoking the generator's returned iterator if it's outdated or no longer needed etc. One issue we had with sagas was testing, since in order to mock a scenario you may need to step N number of times to get there.

Comment: Your answer intrigues me. Can you provide an example where throwing an error does not contain a stack trace? I haven't ecountered any situation yet where `throw` would not provide me with a stack trace. Although, I might be understanding your answer wrong...

Comment: well, if you catch an error and don't forward anything, that's the simplest way it can happen. I've had issues debugging asynchronous code in chrome dev tools (node / puppeteer / chromium), and sometimes I end up looking at random compiler code, which indicates something wrong with the stack trace, possibly dealing with cross-frame permissions and the driver